# Regex to extract part of line that match

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to write a regex to get the last word of each line of a file that start with "A" and end with "/"

```
grep '^A.*/$' list_svn.txt
```

This give the whole line:`A  Java/SYSTEM_A/Sources/branch/developerA/src/org/hl7/v3/`but what I want is just "v3" string.

I tried awk but without success too.

```
grep '^A.*/$' list_svn.txt | awk -F '/' '{print $0, $(NF-1)}'
>> Java/SYSTEM_A/Sources/branch/developerA/src/org/hl7/v3/ v3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `grep` altogether as using awk you can do:

```
awk -F/ '/^A.*\/$/ {print $(NF-1)}' list_svn.txt

v3
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep and look-arounds:

```
$ grep -Po '^A.*/\K[^/]*(?=/$)' <<< 'A  Java/SYSTEM_A/Sources/branch/developerA/src/org/hl7/v3/'
v3
```

`-P` enables Perl regular expressions (required for look-ahead and look-behind), and `-o` returns only the match.

The `\K` acts as a variable length look-behind: "match everything up to here but don't include it in the match". The actual match is a sequence of characters other than `/`, and the `(?=/$)` bit stands for "followed by a `/` and the end of the line" (but also not included in match).